# CLR unloaded due to security data definition language

Tags: security, sql-server-2019, sql-clr

Today, we got a very weird situation. We added a SQL login to our database server. After adding this login, SQL unloaded a critical CLR routine "due to security data definition language" (error 10310). As a result several user processed crashed. The CLRs unloaded in all the registered databases, but the new login had nothing to do with these databases. The databases using the CLR have the TRUSTWORTHY setting to on.

Any idea why creating a regular SQL login is causing this issue? It's certainly NOT a memory issue, plenty of GB available for the OS. We fixed this issue by executing TRUSTWORTHY and registering the CLR, but we're a little afraid if this happens again when adding another login.

Configuration: SQL server 2019 CU20 Enterprise, 512GB memory, 384GB for SQL

Comment: Hello: 1) How many custom assemblies do you have? 2) You say `TRUSTWORTHY` is `ON` in the DBs containing the assemblies, but then say the issue was fixed by "executing TRUSTWORTHY". What does that mean? 3) Did you actually re-`CREATE` the assemblies? 4) Did you try executing the CLR functionality again, after it got unloaded? If so, did it error? If so, what error? 4) What Login(s) own the DBs containing the assemblies? 5) Did the new Login belong to any server Roles? 6) Did assemblies get unloaded immediately upon creating the Login? 7) Have you reproduced this in non-Production environments?

Comment: "*4) What Login(s) own the DBs containing the assemblies?*"...and is it possible the Owner of those databases changed somehow?

Comment: 1) 2 assemblies: 1 for compressing JSON and 1 for decompressing JSON
2) This server is part of an AG. At every failover we de-register the CLR , enable TRUSTWORTHY and register the CLR again in order to keep it working (figured it out this was the only was to have it running)  Since the CLR's were gone after this issue, I ran this step to fix the problem 3) yes, after the crash, see 2 4) Don't know how to determin that, they are recreated in a jobstep after a failover (service account) 5) no 6)  Yes, after creating the login 7) we tried, but with no success

Comment: Willfred, just a heads up that you need to tag someone for them to get notified that you replied. E.g. like this @SolomonRutzky. Also, please put updated information like answers to questions in your original Post so it's easier to read and doesn't get missed in the comments by anyone else who comes to see your question. Then you can just add a reply comment tagging who you're replying to let them know you've updated your Post.

Comment: Also, you can check the database owner in SSMS by right clicking on the Database, going to Properties, and then under the General section it should say the Owner.

Comment: @JD Thanks for the help and the excellent question (yes, a change of DB ownership would be a security event for SQLCLR in a TRUSTWORTHY-enabled DB). Wilfred, thanks for the info. I will take a look later today. Please also answer JD's question about changing DB ownership.

Comment: @WilfredvanDijk For #4a (sorry, didn't realize I used "4" twice), have you tried executing the JSON compress/decompress functions after it got "unloaded"? For #4b, execute `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(USER_SID(1)) AS [dbo's Login];` in the DB with the assemblies. Has this Login changed? 8) For failovers, why exactly do you DROP and re-CREATE the assemblies? I don't think I've ever heard of someone doing that before. 9) What do you mean by "the CLR's were gone"? Do you mean that the assemblies had been dropped and no longer existed? If so, what do you mean by "de-registering" them as part of the job?

Comment: @WilfredvanDijk  10) What do you mean by "unloaded"? Do you mean that the assemblies are dropped and no longer exist in the DB, or do you mean that they are unloaded from memory? 11) Does this new Login get created upon each failover? Is it being added to the DBs containing the assemblies? How does it fit into this scenario? --- so far all of these pieces seem unrelated, so I get the sense that either something rather consequential isn't being mentioned, or perhaps some terminology is not being understood the same by all of us.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky the problem occured after the login was created, before a user was created. Regarding (10): the term "unloaded" is part of the SQL error message and it was indeed unloaded. which resulted in a lot of errors. Regarding (8) this is a result from a previous DBA, it might be not the optimal solution, but that's something for a different question. regarding (11) no, it's a one time action, we are syncing logins with DBAtools

Comment: Wilfred: I'm still confused by the description of this issue. I really need question #9 above answered. Usually, the term "unloaded", especially in error messages, refers to the assembly being removed from memory. Assemblies are loaded into memory the first time a method within them is referenced, and they can stay in memory until available memory decreases and SQL Server needs it for queries, or if there's a security change that might affect how the CLR method(s) function. If the assembly is merely unloaded from memory, that's a non-issue as it'll be loaded again (continued...) (ping @J.D.)

Comment: ...the next time one of it's methods is referenced. "Unloaded" doesn't mean dropped, In fact, outside of the slight performance hit of having to load the assembly into memory again, you generally wouldn't even know that the assembly was "unloaded" if you weren't looking at the error message. Hence "unloaded" error messages are usually an issue of performance, not functionality. This is why I asked #4a, "did you try executing the JSON compress method after seeing the unloaded error message?" If not, you need to. Does it work? Or does the function no longer exist? That would be really odd if so.